# Could Davlik be moved inside the linux kernel for performance?

Tags: android, architecture, kernel

This is a very high-level architecture question. Why hasn't a JVM been moved into
the linux kernel, where it could be more efficient (including just-in-time compiled code).

I realize this is abhorrent to minimal-kernel fans, but Linux is not one of those OSs,
it seems. A JVM kernel module that could be controlled via a `/dev` entry would be possible.

Why not?

Comment: You're confusing Dalvik with JVM. JVM runs on top of HAL for machines with an OS while Dalvik was designed to run on the Droid kernel. What I'm saying, Dalvik is for mobile systems and is not nor will it be a replacement of the JVM.

Answer (score 2):

Moving something into the kernel does not, by itself "make it go faster".  What it can do in some exceptional cases is allow alternate approaches to be used.  Until you have some way of taking advantage of being in kernel, there is absolutely no benefit to being in kernel.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that being in the kernel isn't "the simple answer".  I was thinking about reducing the copying that goes on when (any) JVM makes its underlying-OS calls.  (Clearly loading the bytecodes would require copying from userspace to the kernelized jvm, but that's only at startup.)  My understanding is that any JVM makes calls to the OS to perform the functions that JVM supports.

Answer (score 2):

I can name at least several reasons (surely there are much more):

1. programming and debugging in kernel mode is much more complicated and tricky. What you can easily do in user-mode would require lots of hand-coding and significant time for debugging in kernel-mode.
2. moving JVM to kernel mode would eliminate possibility to use JNI to native modules.
3. security reasons - isolated separate JVMs run in different processes each having different permissions. This would not be possible (without lots of additional coding) in kernel mode.

Comment: 1 Yes everything's harder in the kernel, but this is an architectural question, not a schedule estimate :-)  2. Good point.  I've used JNIs a couple of times, but not all apps do.  3. Yes I figured massive rewriting would be necessary so as *not* to make the calls that (in user jvms) go through the OS system call mechanism.

Comment: @DAH JFYI: StackOverflow is not a discussion forum but a question/answer site. If you want to argue or discuss something, you need to find a discussion place. It's not that I criticize you in any way, yet I think I need to explain what we are doing (and what we are not doing) here.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be more efficient; it might well be *less* efficient.  Every time you want to work with data, the data lives outside the kernel (unless you've also loaded your programs and whatever data they want directly into the kernel) and at least two context switches will need to happen; if the interpreter is outside of the kernel, no context switches are necessary (unless that data has to be read from somewhere (a file, the user, the network, whatever).

Moreover, those "read from somewhere" cases will incur additional context switches *even if requested by the kernel*, because there's a lot of stuff going on behind the scenes to get that data.

(Context switches are expensive.  They're a bit like kicking the CPU in the head and telling it to look at something else when it stops seeing stars; then it needs to write down what it was doing before you kicked it, and then go read its notes about what you just told it to do.)

Comment: Thank you, and the other commenters.  You and others have pointed out that benfits would be application-dependent and greatly complicate life (which I knew) but you've all pointed out things I overlooked.  ...... As far as a context switch, yes.. expensive for programmers brains too, which is why we need quiet uninterrupted time... which some managers don't get... you should avoid those workplaces..  Programmers can thrash too.